# Java JComboBox prevent listener from triggering on select

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have 5 combo boxes, and all 5 of them have the exact same listener attached that does the same exact thing (which is call sort method).

However one of the combo boxes (let's call it `special`) has an additional listener attached, and that listener causes other combo boxes to change their value.

Thus what happens is when the `special` combo box is selected, the sorting method gets called 5 times.

How do I change the value of other 4 combo boxes when `special` combo box has value selected, without triggering their listeners.

Comment: `PropertyChangeEvent`?

Comment: You could use a "mutation" flag, which when set, should indicate that the second listener shouldn't process the event and simply ignore it...

Comment: @MadProgrammer so I should have 5 mutations flags to handle it? Guess that seems to be the simplest way, since anything else didn't yield results. If you want post it as answer and I will accept it as correct

Comment: That depends, if none of the "child" combo boxes should update when the "parent" changes in general, then you only need one, if on the hand, the "child's" state is depended on the "parent", then yes, you'll need more then one...